# Show that $\|f\|^{2}$ attains a minimum value on the interior of $B$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am looking for any help, hints, or suggestions in how to go about this problem from a previous qualifying exam.

We are given a smooth mapping $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ whose differential $df_{p}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is of rank $n$ and we have that $\|f(x)-x\|<\frac{1}{2}$. Here $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an open subset which contains the closed unit ball $B=B_{1}(0)$. The problem asks us to show that $\|f\|^{2}$ attains a minimum on the interior of  $B$.

As of right now, the only thing that comes to mind is the inverse function theorem, that there is an open subset $V \subset U$ where $f$ is an diffeomorphism on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smoothness and rank of the differential is a red herring.

1. $B$ is compact, so a minimum is attained somewhere on $B$.
2. $\lVert f(0)\rVert < \frac{1}{2}$, since $\lVert f(x) - x\rVert < \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$.
3. $\lVert x\rVert \geqslant 1 \implies \lVert f(x)\rVert = \bigl\lVert x - \bigl(x-f(x)\bigr)\bigr\rVert \geqslant \lVert x\rVert - \lVert x - f(x)\rVert > \lVert x\rVert - \frac{1}{2} \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$.

So we know one point in the interior of $B$ where $\lVert f\rVert$ attains a smaller value than at any point in $U \setminus \operatorname{int}(B)$, hence the minimum of $\lVert f\rVert$ on $B$ is attained in the interior of $B$, and it is a (the) global minimum. Of course $\lVert f\rVert^2$ has local or global minima at exactly the same points as $\lVert f\rVert$, since $t \mapsto t^2$ is strictly increasing on $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: I suggest changing the third one to $\|x\|\geq1\implies\dots$ since (I think) the function of interest is $U\to\mathbb R$, not just $B\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, $\lVert x\rVert \geqslant 1$ is the safe way, works whether $B$ or $U$ is the domain of interest. Thanks, @JoonasIlmavirta.

Comment: The question marks should be $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @user135520 Can you prove the inequalities when you insert $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: actually, OP hasn't said that the closed unit ball is a subset of $U$ :)

Comment: @user251257 True, but speaking of "the interior of $B$" would be pointless if $B$ is the open unit ball. Nevertheless, if it should be the open unit ball, we look at $\lVert x\rVert \geqslant 1-\varepsilon$ for a suitable $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm a little embarrassed to ask, but would you be willing to provide more information on part 3?

Comment: @user135520 Sure. But first, can you confirm that $B$ is the closed unit ball, or is it the open unit ball? [For the closed unit ball, we have a simpler way to give the proof by using the boundary sphere, but it's not a fundamental difference.]

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I forgot to say. It is the closed unit ball

Comment: @user135520 I've elaborated. If anything is unclear, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks this is a big relief.

Comment: Is it possible to show additionally that $f$ has a zero in $B$?

Comment: @user5579085 Yes. To deduce that, the assumption on the rank of the differential is helpful. It would also hold without a differentiability assumption, but then the proof would require some nontrivial topological results. With the assumption that $df_p$ is invertible everywhere, it is an immediate consequence of the inverse function theorem that $f$ is an open mapping, and if $\lVert f\rVert$ had a local minimum at $p$ with $f(p) \neq 0$, then $f$ wouldn't be open at $p$. So every local (and in particular the global) minimum of $\lVert f\rVert$ is a zero of $f$.

Comment: How exactly would a local minimum of $||f||$ with $f(p)\ne 0$ contradict that $f$ is open?

Comment: @user5579085 Let $\lVert f(p)\rVert = r > 0$. Then for small enough $\varepsilon > 0$ the image $f\bigl(B_{\varepsilon}(p)\bigr)$ is contained in $A_r = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lVert x\rVert \geqslant r\}$, since $\lVert f\rVert$ has a local minimum at $p$. But $A_r$ is not a neighbourhood of $f(p)$, so $f$ cannot be an open map then.

Comment: That $p$ is a local minimum means that $||f(p)|| < ||f(x)||$ for all $x$ in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $p$. Sorry for perhaps too basic questions, but I can't see why this implies that $f(B_\epsilon(p))$ is contained in $A_r$. And if it does, we need a contradiction to the fact that $f(B_\epsilon(p))$ is open. Why does the fact that $A_r$ is not a neighborhood of $f(p)$ (I assume this means an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ containing $f(p)$) imply that $f(B_\epsilon(p))$ is not open? Let me know if it's better to post a separate question including these.

Comment: @user5579085 If $\varepsilon > 0$ is so small that $\lVert f(p)\rVert \leqslant \lVert f(y)\rVert$ for all $y \in B_{\varepsilon}(p)$, then by defintion of $r$ we have $\lVert f(y)\rVert \geqslant r$, i.e. $f(y) \in A_r$ for all $y \in B_{\varepsilon}(p)$. I use the definition of neighbourhood that states "contains an open set containing …", a neighbourhood need not be open itself. But that makes not much of a difference. If $f\bigl(B_{\varepsilon}(p)\bigr)$ were open (or just a neighbourhood of $f(p)$), it would contain a ball $B_{\delta}\bigl(f(p)\bigr)$ for some $\delta > 0$.

Comment: But such a ball would contain points $x$ with $\lVert x\rVert < r$ (e.g. $(1 - \eta)\cdot f(p)$ for sufficiently small $\eta > 0$), and hence not be contained in $A_r$.

Comment: Thank you. The part with $||x|| < r$ (e.g. $(1-\eta ) \cdot f(p)$) doesn't agree with my geometric vision. $A_r$ is the exterior of an open ball. $f(p)\in f(B_\epsilon(p))$  is contained in that ball. Consider a "subball" centered at $p$. The distance from the origin to a point in the large ball $f(B_\epsilon(p))$ and hence in the subball is at least $r$. The statement $||x|| < r$ says that there is a point in the ball with the distance from it to the origin being less than $r$.

Comment: @user5579085 The origin is the centre of the ball. $A_r$ is the complement of the open ball with centre $0$ and radius $r$.

Comment: How is that possible? If you meant that one could take $r=(1-\eta) f(p)$, then I still don't get it, since any point in the ball is at least as far as $r$ units from the origin.

Comment: Yes, so any point in $A_r$ is at distance at least $r$ from $0$. In particular, this is true for any point of $f(B_\epsilon(p))$ and for any point of any subball of $f(B_\epsilon(p))$. So no point $x$ of $f(B_\epsilon(p))$ can have the property that $||x|| < r$ as far as I can see. Probably I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: @user5579085 $f(p)$ is on the sphere with radius $r$ and centre $0$. Every ball $B_{\delta}\bigl(f(p)\bigr)$ therefore contains points whose distance from $0$ is less than $r$. That's the kind of ball I was referring to with "such a ball". Since $f\bigl(B_{\varepsilon}(p)\bigr)$ is contained in $A_r$, $f\bigl(B_{\varepsilon}(p)\bigr)$ cannot contain $B_{\delta}\bigl(f(p)\bigr)$ for any $\delta > 0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. My confusion was because I didn't realize that $f(p)$ lies on the sphere, which was the initial assumption... Thanks a lot!